# How to make google show my website with category layout

Tags: search, seo

All:

I wonder how can I make the google search result of my website formated and list category as google itself? Is that called SEO optimization?

Basically what I want my website looks in google search results just like

enter "google", "github", "stackoverflow" in google search, it will show categories and probably a search bar

Thanks

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse, that comes under SEO. 
Those are called site links, they are automatically generated by google's algorithm depending on the traffic to various important pages of your site.

Login and contact pages are automatically detected if you have right seo structure. 
sub domains are also listed automatically if you have any.

in case of stack overflow, it shows up important pages and subomains such as java and python which are again individual communitites, that made google to show them in search result.

more about google site links is [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, I will read and give a try to that. BTW, do you have a step-by-step tutorial or something simple and clear?

Comment: Yes, these links might help you, http://www.relishtraymedia.com/blog/bid/257788/SEO-Sitelinks-How-to-Get-Google-Subheadings-in-Search-Results

Answer (score 0):

Well Google picks them automatically, there are no way to put links under your domain as categories. But if Google picks wrong url than Google gives you facility to remove that unwanted url using "Demote a sitelink URL"

Hope this will help.